# Hanging of Apache web server until Client "waiting" for TTFB

Tags: linux

We have a strange situation on our Debian Linux server.

**Our trouble/problem/question:**

If some visitor call the website - Apache receive visitor's request and just stuck on it for about 1-20 seconds (for first request) AND then possibly for some other (random) objects (images, java-scripts, html, php and other loaded files) of the same website, during the same session, for static and dynamic contents. And it does not matter if it was call for statically picture/image or dynamical php-file with database requests.

The same thing within PM2 (socket node.js). It's simply stucks time to time between server-client messages for the same time like Apache.

As a result, the website loads for more than a minute and two weeks ago it was under 1.2 seconds.

There are no errors in logs...

**What doing Apache web server on my Server until Client "waiting" for TTFB?**

Some information about the server:

Two HDDs SATA /dev/sda and /dev/sdb in software RAID1.
(All RAID1 tests and HDDs tests was good, all HDDs are healthy)

On server running applications: Apache2, nginx (as reverse-proxy for static content), locally MySQL (MyISAM + InnoDB), locally MongoDB and PM2 (socket node.js). The network routing, NICs and DNS are 100% OK.
All about 10000 visitors/day.

We have tried strace for Apache, but there are too much data (for ca. 5 second more then 1Gb) and we can't find our thread between others for system calls.

```
Linux host 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

PHP running as Apache-module.

RAID1 status:

```
 # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md2 : active raid1 sda3[2] sdb3[1]
      1936077760 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda2[2] sdb2[1]
      523968 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[2] sdb1[1]
      16768896 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

HDDs health:

```
# smartctl -H /dev/sdb
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.2.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

# smartctl -H /dev/sda
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.2.0-4-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

Journaling on both database systems (Mongo and MySQL) is deactivated in their configurations, but it works here on EXT4 file system.

Here some data about running processes with highest IOs:

```
15:13:51 15313 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   39.51 K/s  0.00 %  0.02 % mongod_config --config /etc/mongod_config.conf
15:13:51 27418 be/4 root        0.00 K/s   11.85 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -c5
15:13:53   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  382.84 K/s  0.00 % 10.95 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:13:55 25191 be/4 nginx      27.46 K/s    0.00 K/s  0.00 %  0.90 % nginx: worker process
15:13:55 27418 be/4 root        0.00 K/s   15.69 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -c5
15:13:55 27801 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   23.54 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:13:56   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  165.80 K/s  0.00 % 13.04 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:13:56 27418 be/4 root        0.00 K/s   11.84 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -c5
15:14:01   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  391.00 K/s  0.00 %  7.43 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:01 27418 be/4 root        0.00 K/s   19.75 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -c5
15:14:02   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  228.93 K/s  0.00 % 14.90 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:02 15059 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s   15.79 K/s  0.00 %  0.04 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:02 27627 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   19.74 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:03 27418 be/4 root        0.00 K/s   11.84 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -c5
15:14:03 27587 be/4 www-data    0.00 K/s  702.42 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
15:14:03 27589 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s  966.81 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:05 14959 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s  236.84 K/s  0.00 %  0.09 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:06   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  197.61 K/s  0.00 % 46.68 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:06 14959 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s  529.58 K/s  0.00 %  0.39 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:06 27418 be/4 root        0.00 K/s   11.86 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -c5
15:14:07   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  138.08 K/s  0.00 % 12.15 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:07 18365 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s   11.84 K/s  0.00 %  0.04 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:10 25191 be/4 nginx      15.79 K/s    0.00 K/s  0.00 %  2.99 % nginx: worker process
15:14:11 25192 be/4 nginx      39.48 K/s    3.95 K/s  0.00 %  2.77 % nginx: worker process
15:14:11 25199 be/4 nginx      19.74 K/s    0.00 K/s  0.00 %  0.69 % nginx: worker process
15:14:11 25194 be/4 nginx      23.69 K/s    3.95 K/s  0.00 %  0.01 % nginx: worker process
15:14:12   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  464.09 K/s  0.00 %  6.12 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:14 27418 be/4 root        0.00 K/s   11.84 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -c5
15:14:14 27605 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   23.69 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:16   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  244.83 K/s  0.00 % 38.10 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:16 14959 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s  418.59 K/s  0.00 %  0.32 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:16 27342 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   15.80 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:18 27418 be/4 root        0.00 K/s   15.80 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -c5
15:14:20 27398 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   27.10 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:21   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  402.19 K/s  0.00 %  9.45 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:21 27328 be/4 www-data    0.00 K/s   11.83 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
15:14:22 25192 be/4 nginx      23.72 K/s    0.00 K/s  0.00 %  0.41 % nginx: worker process
15:14:22 27595 be/4 www-data    0.00 K/s   11.86 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
15:14:23   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  307.91 K/s  0.00 % 10.74 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:23 27549 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   15.79 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:25   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  247.60 K/s  0.00 %  9.74 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:25 27388 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   27.51 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:26   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s   90.01 K/s  0.00 % 33.82 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:26 25195 be/4 nginx      15.65 K/s    0.00 K/s  0.00 %  1.71 % nginx: worker process
15:14:26 14959 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s  508.77 K/s  0.00 %  0.34 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:27 25195 be/4 nginx       0.00 K/s   11.62 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % nginx: worker process
15:14:30 15313 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   35.57 K/s  0.00 %  0.04 % mongod_config --config /etc/mongod_config.conf
15:14:31   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  351.53 K/s  0.00 %  4.41 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:33   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s   43.37 K/s  0.00 %  7.53 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:33 15059 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s   11.83 K/s  0.00 %  0.04 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:33 27794 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   15.77 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:33 27835 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   11.83 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:34   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  106.56 K/s  0.00 % 12.32 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:34 14977 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s   11.84 K/s  0.00 %  0.06 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:34 27418 be/4 root        0.00 K/s   15.79 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -c5
15:14:37   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  242.20 K/s  0.00 %  8.01 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:37 25195 be/4 nginx      11.72 K/s    0.00 K/s  0.00 %  1.01 % nginx: worker process
15:14:37 14977 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s   11.72 K/s  0.00 %  0.04 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:37 27634 be/4 www-data    0.00 K/s   15.63 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
15:14:37 27636 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   19.53 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:37 27842 be/4 www-data    0.00 K/s   11.72 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % apache2 -k start
15:14:39 27418 be/4 root        0.00 K/s   11.77 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % rsyslogd -c5
15:14:39 27849 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   31.39 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:41 27801 be/4 mongodb   118.35 K/s   43.39 K/s  0.00 %  1.34 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:41 22209 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s   11.83 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:44   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  541.22 K/s  0.00 % 51.74 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:44 14959 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s 1335.27 K/s  0.00 %  0.85 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:44 18604 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s   11.85 K/s  0.00 %  0.16 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:45 25195 be/4 nginx      23.68 K/s    0.00 K/s  0.00 %  0.90 % nginx: worker process
15:14:46   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s  327.37 K/s  0.00 %  9.90 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:46 18362 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s   11.83 K/s  0.00 %  0.05 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:46 27800 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   11.83 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15:14:47   339 be/3 root        0.00 K/s   46.87 K/s  0.00 %  7.34 % [jbd2/md2-8]
15:14:47 18504 be/4 mysql       0.00 K/s   15.62 K/s  0.00 %  0.06 % mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
15:14:50 27867 be/4 mongodb     0.00 K/s   23.64 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

From Apache config:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          7
    MinSpareServers       7
    MaxSpareServers       15
    ServerLimit           1024
    MaxClients            1024
    MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE1** *(additional information)*

```
 # iostat
Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 (host)  08/19/2018      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           8.86    0.00    3.80    1.02    0.00   86.32

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sdb              96.78      3093.98       498.35 2022098528  325699718
sda              96.09      3085.66       498.35 2016660127  325699718
md0               0.01         0.01         0.02       4002      10552
md1               0.05         0.02         0.05      13068      32539
md2              88.37       252.24       496.79  164852095  324679412
```

- 

```
# cat /etc/fstab
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
/dev/md/0 none swap sw 0 0
/dev/md/1 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
/dev/md/2 / ext4 defaults 0 0
```

**UPDATE2** *(additional information)*

```
    # dmesg -T
.....
    .....
        [Sun Aug 19 17:03:28 2018] type=1300 audit(1534691393.580:36049): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=40 a3=17344e0 items=0 ppid=16922 pid=16923 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/sbin/xtables-multi" key=(null)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:04:14 2018] type=1325 audit(1534691439.884:36050): table=filter family=2 entries=85
        [Sun Aug 19 17:04:14 2018] type=1300 audit(1534691439.884:36050): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=40 a3=1b12660 items=0 ppid=16956 pid=16957 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/sbin/xtables-multi" key=(null)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:05:02 2018] type=1325 audit(1534691487.740:36051): table=filter family=2 entries=86
        [Sun Aug 19 17:05:02 2018] type=1300 audit(1534691487.740:36051): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=40 a3=1f417d0 items=0 ppid=16993 pid=16994 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/sbin/xtables-multi" key=(null)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU7: Core power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU1: Core power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU4: Core power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU3: Core power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU5: Core power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU0: Core power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU2: Core power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU6: Core power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU1: Package power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU4: Package power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU3: Package power limit notification (total events = 11376)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU5: Package power limit notification (total events = 11375)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU0: Package power limit notification (total events = 11376)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU2: Package power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU6: Package power limit notification (total events = 11376)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU7: Package power limit notification (total events = 11377)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU3: Core power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU0: Core power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU7: Core power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU1: Core power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU5: Core power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU2: Core power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU4: Core power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU6: Core power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU0: Package power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU7: Package power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU1: Package power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU5: Package power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU2: Package power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU4: Package power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU6: Package power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:09:19 2018] CPU3: Package power limit normal
        [Sun Aug 19 17:11:48 2018] type=1325 audit(1534691893.367:36052): table=filter family=2 entries=87
        [Sun Aug 19 17:11:48 2018] type=1300 audit(1534691893.367:36052): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=40 a3=185a7d0 items=0 ppid=17942 pid=17943 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/sbin/xtables-multi" key=(null)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:13:28 2018] type=1325 audit(1534691993.655:36053): table=filter family=2 entries=86
        [Sun Aug 19 17:13:28 2018] type=1300 audit(1534691993.655:36053): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=40 a3=950650 items=0 ppid=17983 pid=17984 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/sbin/xtables-multi" key=(null)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:14:14 2018] type=1325 audit(1534692039.907:36054): table=filter family=2 entries=85
        [Sun Aug 19 17:14:14 2018] type=1300 audit(1534692039.907:36054): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=40 a3=1ec14e0 items=0 ppid=18025 pid=18026 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/sbin/xtables-multi" key=(null)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:15:02 2018] type=1325 audit(1534692087.763:36055): table=filter family=2 entries=84
        [Sun Aug 19 17:15:02 2018] type=1300 audit(1534692087.763:36055): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=40 a3=84a360 items=0 ppid=18133 pid=18134 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/sbin/xtables-multi" key=(null)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:15:28 2018] type=1325 audit(1534692114.219:36056): table=filter family=2 entries=83
        [Sun Aug 19 17:15:28 2018] type=1300 audit(1534692114.219:36056): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=40 a3=1280370 items=0 ppid=18243 pid=18244 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/sbin/xtables-multi" key=(null)
        [Sun Aug 19 17:17:14 2018] type=1325 audit(1534692219.563:36057): table=filter family=2 entries=84
        [Sun Aug 19 17:17:14 2018] type=1300 audit(1534692219.563:36057): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=3 a1=0 a2=40 a3=189b4e0 items=0 ppid=18389 pid=18390 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/sbin/xtables-multi" key=(null)
```

- 

```
mysql> show variables like 'thread_cache_size';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| thread_cache_size | 8     |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show status like 'Threads%';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Threads_cached    | 7     |
| Threads_connected | 1     |
| Threads_created   | 3082  |
| Threads_running   | 1     |
+-------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you have kernel messages with warnings like `EXT4-fs warning (device md2): ext4_dx_add_entry: Directory index full!`? Could you post `journalctl -k -b > /home/user/journal.log` somewhere at pastebin-service like https://pastebin.ubuntu.com

Comment: I don't have a journalctl, but there are no warnings or errors information found due 'grep' for 'ext4' or 'Derectory index'.
PS: this problem we have since last 14 days.

Comment: There are two folders on server with huge amount of files, but not millions.
In this folder stored chat sessions (main thing of this server is a Chat service)
# ls -1 /var/www/vhosts/host/httpdocs/data/sessions/ | wc -l
77763
In this folder stored chats configs for each client: 
# ls -1 /var/www/vhosts/host/httpdocs/public/chats/s/ | wc -l
172373

Comment: I'm newbe in community posting and here on this website and I've not used such services like pastebin. Now I'd read about this service and I'd post there within link here). Thank you for your patience and understanding.

Comment: Your first problem is mysql. Look at `Threads_created` - it's `3082`, and at the same time `Threads_cached` is only `7`. This values should be comparable - difference in thousands is real big problem. To solve the problem you have to increase `thread_cache_size`. Change it to `thread_cache_size = 36` in mysql config, restart mysql daemon and check value `Threads_created` again.  Additionally, check and post `show variables like "wait_timeout";` and `show variables like "interactive_timeout";` for mysql.

Comment: The `Threads_created` value slowly increases and now it stopped at 9 within 5 minutes.
My `wait_timeout` is equal `interactive_timeout` is 28800.

Comment: `28800` is 8 hours. Are you sure you need to keep connections so long? Try to change `wait_timeout = 300` and  `interactive_timeout = 300` in mysql config. Only check this values caused no problems for you. Google `wait_timeout` for mysql and read carefully.

Comment: Another questions to you. Which of servers `apache` or `nginx` serves static content? Have you tried to serve static content with `nginx` only without `apache`? Do you use nginx as caching server for dynamic content with cache in RAM?

Comment: You are right about cache you'd written before and this both variables is only fine tuning. But how you would explain a 'waiting' by calling of statical image, which has only five bytes?
I've Plesk panel on server with built-in Apache and nginx installed. Through Plesk it's only possible to run nginx for a static content as a 'reverse-proxy', what I've done.
"dynamic content with cache in RAM" - I'll be happy to make thomesing like that.

Comment: But our application is ready and I try only do not to touch this).

Comment: Stop. You wrote: 'Through Plesk it's only possible to run nginx for a static content as a 'reverse-proxy', what I've done.' This means the small only five bytes file has been served by `nginx` and `apache` hasn't involved in the process. Am I right? By the way, the mentioned by you mysql 'fine tuning' can save up to 50% of your system resources.

Comment: I've set a minimum size of file, which must be served by nginx and the rest of static files will be served directly by apache. 
Here is the schema 'how it was done' by Plesk
 https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/web-servers/apache-and-nginx-web-servers-linux/apache-with-nginx.70837/

Comment: Do you have the problem when `nginx` serves a static file?

Comment: I've tested - nginx does the job perfectly, but after that Apache does their breakpoint. Like it waits for something... (database or hdd or something like that)

Comment: Additionally I want to say: we have as 'default' http:// with 301 rewrite rule to https:// in .htaccess. Interesting, that before to do this 'rewrite' it waits too.

Comment: Could you post your `.htaccess` file(-s)?

Comment: Could you post output of: `curl -s -w '\nLookup time:\t\t%{time_namelookup}\nConnect time:\t\t%{time_connect}\nSSL handshake time:\t%{time_appconnect}\nPre-Transfer time:\t%{time_pretransfer}\nRedirect time:\t\t%{time_redirect}\nStart transfer time:\t%{time_starttransfer}\n\nTotal time:\t\t%{time_total}\n' -o /dev/null http://yoursite.org` - FOR BOTH `http://yoursite.org` and `https://yoursite.org`

Comment: It does not make sense because there are many things will run as htaccess and php-rewritings.
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/rPGxRpqHnY/
I do not see at all that the apache touched files before. It waits before...

Comment: As I said before, the time each time is significantly different, although in these queries it is not visible
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/X27XcZcwN9/

Comment: And where is the problem? TTFB is almost zero.

Comment: Have you checked a DDoS attack when problem appears? Also try the `curl` command from above for different files, php-scripts etc.

Comment: No, it isn't always. Or possibly I have done some changes (I'm sitting on this problem many days) or you helped me with suggestions.
Anyway, I will watch server.
And now I will also check the Chat service, because there are was the same waiting time between messages sending’s-receiving’s.

Comment: Hello Bob, it's better with the files. But you said that the values MySQL should be better. Now they are https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Sk7bkCznXj/ And the problem with the chat is the same. I've found, that the problem comes from node.js

Comment: Hi! I'm busy today, I'll look a bit later.